# Output for RAID status

Tags: 14.04, raid

I am currently trying to check the status of my ubuntu computer but I am having some trouble.

```
$ lspci | greb RAID
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 SATA Controller [RAID mode](rev 04)
```

From what I understand, this is a software RAID. After that I do the next command of `cat /proc/mdstat`. The output is

```
Personalities :
unused devices: <none>
```

What does this mean? Is my computer using RAID?

Comment: Is a PCI bus controller operating in RAID mode software RAID or hardware RAID?

Comment: From what I learn at this website https://www.bytemark.co.uk/docs/servers/console/check-server-raid/, It is a software RAID

Comment: I don't see that in the page you linked to. It doesn't mention Intel Rapid Storage at all.

Comment: Isnt it this? If the response contains

3ware — you’re probably using 3ware RAID.
Hewlett-Packard — you’re probably using HP RAID.
megaRAID — you’re probably using MegaRAID.
anything else (or no output) — you’re probably using software RAID.

The computer I am using is runnning in a server

Comment: keyword: "probably". Intel Rapid Storage is probably more common than any of those three now.

Comment: Oh okay. I got another question on RAID. I have a server that is using hardware RAID 1, told by my supervisor. For my knowledge of RAID 1, it means there will be separate copies of the whole system in different storage.  Heres the question:
If I want to do a patch on this server (Lubuntu 14.04) and restore it if something go wrong. Is it before i start to patch, I remove the additional storage containing the system and patch it. If something goes wrong, i change the storage of the one i took out and the one that is remain in the server.